# How to implement Inversion of control c# - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, inversion-of-control

I'm learning on how to implement inversion of control in the wpf application through the below link

https://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/implementing-the-inversion-of-control-pattern-in-c.htm

The intent of the application is to load the data from table to combobox. The code works fine without any issue. So as a part of learning ooad design principle I thought below is the perfect case on which the highlevel module (Viewmodel) depend upon lowerlevel module (populatetab2combobox). I believe here we can apply dependency inversion. on reading online most of them started with inversion of control as a first step towards implementing Dependency inversion.

I just want to iterate that I don't have prior experience in oops principle. I might be wrong in my assumption. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Window.xaml :

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding populatecombobox.modeltogetusername}" Width="155" Margin="0,-20,-180,137">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
```

View Model :

**Code without implementing  inversion of control(This works fine without any issue):**

```
//Class to populate the combobox

public class populatetab2combobox
{
    public ObservableCollection<comboboxdata> modeltogetusername { get; set; }

    public void getdatausinglinq()
    {
        using (Operations_Productivity_ToolEntities context = new Operations_Productivity_ToolEntities())
        {
            var a1 = from t1 in context.Test_ImportedAuditdata
                     select t1;

            if (modeltogetusername == null)
                modeltogetusername = new ObservableCollection<comboboxdata>();

            foreach (var a in a1.GroupBy(x => x.username).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()))
            {
                modeltogetusername.Add(new comboboxdata
                {
                 username = a.username.ToString()
                });

            }
        }

    }

}


 public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {

/** You can see that I'm calling viewModel class is depended with 
   populatetab2combobox. I believe this is the perfect case for implementing 
   Inversion of control **/

populatetab2combobox_populatecombobox = new populatetab2combobox();
private PopulateDatagrid _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection = new PopulateDatagrid();
private Loadfileintodatabase loaddata = new Loadfileintodatabase();

public PopulateDatagrid Populatedatagridwithobservablecollection {
    get {
        return _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection;
    }
    set {
        if (value != _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection) {
            _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Populatedatagridwithobservablecollection");
        }
    }
}


DataModel dm = new DataModel();

public ViewModel() {
    _populatecombobox.getdatausinglinq();
    DoSomeThingCmd = new RelayCommand(o = >search());
    _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection.getdatausinglinq();
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

#endregion
}
}
```

**Code with implementation of inversion of control(The issue is combobox is empty when i run when IOC implemented):**

```
public interface INofificationAction
{
     void getdatausinglinq();
}



public class populatetab2combobox : INofificationAction
{
    public ObservableCollection<comboboxdata> modeltogetusername { get; set; }

    public void getdatausinglinq()
    {
        using (Operations_Productivity_ToolEntities context = new Operations_Productivity_ToolEntities())
        {
            var a1 = from t1 in context.Test_ImportedAuditdata
                     select t1;

            if (modeltogetusername == null)
                modeltogetusername = new ObservableCollection<comboboxdata>();

            foreach (var a in a1.GroupBy(x => x.username).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()))
            {
                modeltogetusername.Add(new comboboxdata
                {
                 username = a.username.ToString()
                });

            }
        }

    }

}

 public class implementingabstraction
{
    INofificationAction _an;
    public implementingabstraction(INofificationAction action)
    {
        this._an = action;
    }

    public void getdatausinglinq()
    {
        _an.getdatausinglinq();
    }

}


public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
INofificationAction getdata123 = new populatetab2combobox();

populatetab2combobox _populatecombobox = new populatetab2combobox();

public populatetab2combobox populatecombobox {
    get {
        return _populatecombobox;
    }
    set {
        if (value != _populatecombobox) {
            _populatecombobox = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("populatetab2combobox");
        }
    }
}

public RelayCommand DoSomeThingCmd {
    get;
    set;
}
DataModel dm = new DataModel();

public ViewModel() {

    implementingabstraction abs = new implementingabstraction(getdata123);
    abs.getdatausinglinq();
    DoSomeThingCmd = new RelayCommand(o = >search());
    _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection.getdatausinglinq();
}
```

}

questions:

1) since I'm very new to oops based approach.Whether the above usecase is correct.

2) The above code is not working correctly. Can you please point out the mistake in my approach.

Comment: Hi there! Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say the "code is not working". Is it throwing an exception, or what is the intended behavior you hope to achieve that it's not executing?

Comment: Hi, The intended behaviour I expect is, the code populates the data when i run the application without implementing Inversion of control. I want the same while i implement the Inversion of control principle. The issue I'm facing is the data is not populated into the combobox while I implement Inversion of control. The combobox is empty when IOC implemented.